# Android sdk manager doesn't load custom add-ons

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, add-on

I'm trying to add my custom SDK add-on to Android SDK. I successfully installed the zip files one for the library and one for the image and created the repositories that had been successfully validated through "xmllint". I had linked them in the SDK manager, but when I launch, it only fetches URLs without loading anything by-passing validating and parsing steps. Can anyone help me?

Comment: i use android studio IDE

Comment: solved, it was because android studio didn't have permissions to access the http://localhost directories